# how to link storyboard "save" button sent action to code and at the same time return the view back to main when save button is pressed?

Tags: ios5, action, storyboard

i am having trouble using the storyboard. without storyboard my line of codes are as so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Add Login";

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                          target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];
NSLog(@"hello");
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                           initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                           target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

this codes will help me setup my views with 2 button cancel and save on the navi bar.

since i started using storyboard, i created the buttons myself on the storyboard view and i link the cancel key back to navigation controller with style as modal. so when i clicked cancel, it works as it should going back to the previous view. but my save button doesn't work anymore cos it aren't pointing to anything. even when i add the code mentioned above and implement the respective method.

also to note that after using storyboard, the above mentioned code even if i delete them all, doesn't affect my view from how i designed it in storyboard. so i think the code is redundant now right? since even if i change the title in the code, the title set in storyboard shows instead?

```
- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Saved Clicked");
LoginDBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LoginDBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//Create a Login Object.
Login *loginObj = [[Login alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:0];
loginObj.loginDesc = txtloginDesc.text;
loginObj.loginURL = txtloginURL.text;
loginObj.loginUserName = txtloginUserName.text;
loginObj.password = txtpassword.text;

/*NSString *URL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:txtloginURL.text];
 loginObj.loginURL = URL;
 [URL release];
 NSString *username = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:txtloginUserName.text];
 loginObj.loginURL = username;
 [username release];
 NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:txtpassword.text];
 loginObj.loginURL = password;
 [password release];
 */

loginObj.isDirty = NO;
loginObj.isDetailViewHydrated = YES;

//Add the object
[appDelegate addLogin:loginObj];

//Dismiss the controller.
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

what should i do so that i can link the button "save" i made in storyboard to link to the method save_clicked in the .m file?

Update:
i have managed to link the save button to the code by changing (void) to (IBAction) so i am able to save the data. but the view remains after pressing save.

when i try to connect the save button when press to return to the navigation controller in storyboard modally, it returns to the main page but the data ends up not being saved. when i cancel that link and i check my database, the data can be saved but the view still remains the same.